# SAPUI5 add dialog and bind actions

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I have this app, which is split into 2 parts (master, details). How can i add new elements such as buttons and bind actions for them? Should i using jquery or sapui5 has some own methods?

How to bind action (clicking 'Add to cart button' (sap.m.Dialog)) with form (sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm) and when form is filling and submitted, new category and number of category (to the content attribute) should append to existing list.

that is code of my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Просмотр товара</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            /* все элементы VBox'a с шириной во всю строку */
            #myView2--idVBox > div {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" -->

        <script
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            type="text/javascript"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        >
        </script>

        <!-- Страница выбора категории -->
        <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview" >
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="local.controller.Master"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" >
                <Page id="page" title="Выбор категории" showFooter="true">
                    <headerContent>
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://cart" tooltip="Add to cart" />
                    </headerContent>
                    <subHeader>
                        <Toolbar id="searchBar" >
                            <content>
                                <SearchField id="searchField" width="100%" placeholder="Поиск ..." showRefreshButton="true" />
                            </content>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </subHeader>
                    <content>
                        <List id="categoryList" noDataText="Нет данных">
                            <items>
                                <StandardListItem type="Active" counter="5" title="Category 1" press=".pressExample"/>
                                <StandardListItem type="Active" counter="2" title="Category 2" press=".pressExample"/>
                                <StandardListItem type="Active" counter="4" title="Category 3" press=".pressExample"/>
                                <StandardListItem type="Active" counter="7" title="Category 4" press=".pressExample"/>
                            </items>
                        </List>
                    </content>
                    <footer>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <content>
                                <ToolbarSpacer />
                                <Button text="Создать категорию" icon="sap-icon://add" />
                            </content>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </footer>
                </Page>
            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <!-- Детальная страница -->
        <script id="view2" type="sapui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="local.controller.Detail"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" >
                <Page id="page" navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress" title="{Name}" showNavButton="{device>/isPhone}">
                    <content>
                        <ObjectHeader title="Laptop Case" number="78.99" numberUnit="EUR" introActive="false" titleActive="false" iconActive="false">
                            <attributes>
                                <ObjectAttribute text="Red point stories" active="false" />
                                <ObjectAttribute text="Laptop Case with many room for pencils and other stationaries" active="false" />
                                <ObjectAttribute text="789g" active="false" />
                            </attributes>
                            <firstStatus>
                                <ObjectStatus text="Доступен" state="Success" />
                            </firstStatus>
                        </ObjectHeader>
                        <VBox id="idVBox" direction="Column" alignItems="Center">
                            <items>
                                <IconTabBar
                                    expanded="true"
                                    width="100%"
                                    id="idIconTabBar"
                                    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
                                    <items>
                                      <IconTabFilter
                                        icon="sap-icon://begin"
                                        iconColor="Positive"
                                        design="Horizontal"
                                        count="7 из 14"
                                        text="Confirm Ok"
                                        key="Ok" />
                                      <IconTabSeparator icon="sap-icon://open-command-field" />
                                      <IconTabFilter
                                        icon="sap-icon://compare"
                                        iconColor="Critical"
                                        design="Horizontal"
                                        count="5 из 14"
                                        text="Check Heavys"
                                        key="Heavy" />
                                      <IconTabSeparator icon="sap-icon://open-command-field" />
                                      <IconTabFilter
                                        icon="sap-icon://inventory"
                                        iconColor="Negative"
                                        design="Horizontal"
                                        count="2 из 14"
                                        text="Claim Overweights"
                                        key="Overweight" />
                                    </items>
                                    <content>
                                        <List >
                                            <headerToolbar>
                                              <Toolbar>
                                                <Title text="Продукты" level="H2" />
                                                <ToolbarSpacer />
                                                <Button
                                                  icon="sap-icon://settings"
                                                  press="handleButtonPress" />
                                                <Button
                                                  icon="sap-icon://person-placeholder"
                                                  press="handleButtonPress" />
                                                <Button
                                                  icon="sap-icon://drop-down-list"
                                                  press="handleButtonPress" />
                                              </Toolbar>
                                            </headerToolbar>
                                            <infoToolbar>
                                              <Toolbar
                                                active="true"
                                                press="handleInfobarPress" >
                                                <Label text="This is the info bar" />
                                              </Toolbar>
                                            </infoToolbar>
                                            <items>
                                                <StandardListItem
                                                    title = "Power Projector 4713"
                                                    description = "1239102"
                                                    icon = "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-6100.jpg"
                                                    iconDensityAware="false"
                                                    iconInset="false" />

                                                <StandardListItem
                                                    title = "Gladiator MX"
                                                    description = "2212-121-828"
                                                    icon = "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1071.jpg"
                                                    iconDensityAware="false"
                                                    iconInset="false" />

                                                <StandardListItem
                                                    title = "Hurricane GX"
                                                    description = "K47322.1"
                                                    icon = "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1072.jpg"
                                                    iconDensityAware="false"
                                                    iconInset="false" />

                                                <StandardListItem
                                                    title = "Webcam"
                                                    description = "22134T"
                                                    icon = "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1112.jpg"
                                                    iconDensityAware="false"
                                                    iconInset="false" />
                                            </items>
                                        </List>
                                    </content>
                                </IconTabBar>
                            </items>
                        </VBox>

                    </content>
                    <footer>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <content>
                                <ToolbarSpacer />
                                <Button text="Добавить в корзину" icon="sap-icon://add" />
                            </content>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </footer>
                </Page>
            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <!-- Подключение страниц -->
        <script>
            // Controller definition 4 Master
            sap.ui.controller("local.controller.Master", {
                pressExample: function(oEvent) {
                  alert('Нажат элемент '+oEvent.getSource().getTitle());
                }
            });

            // Controller definition 4 Detail
            sap.ui.controller("local.controller.Detail", {

            });

            var splitApp = new sap.m.SplitApp({
                masterPages: [sap.ui.xmlview("myView1", {viewContent:$('#view1').html()})],
                detailPages: [sap.ui.xmlview("myView2", {viewContent:$('#view2').html()})]
            });

            var shell = sap.m.Shell({
                showLogout: false,
                app: splitApp,
            });

            // oView.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/products.json"));

            shell.placeAt('content');



        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a many questions in one thread.

To get started I have the data of your example bound to a model. Also I added a button to add items. Finally I attached a change event to calculate the categories on the master page. Please follow the code changes. It may be a good idea, to work through the "Workthrough" Tutorial on [SAPUI5 Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html)

["JSBIN Example"](http://jsbin.com/hipujo/edit?html,output)

Comment: thanks! this helps me a lot! I will answer some new questions if i get in trouble doing my task under this comments, ok?

Comment: I don't understand how add sorting into master view, that should be a button with popover, which has (1. sort by category name; 2. sort by count value) help me to deal with this.
https://jsfiddle.net/t6a07f0e/

Comment: I don´t believe that there are Coloum Headers in sap.m.List. Use sap.m.Table instead (extends sap.m.ListBase too). You can sort and filter your data using the ListBinding (instance, which I registered the change event) with filter() and sort().

Comment: look here please https://jsbin.com/sinavovuxo/edit?html,output I add sorter at List (master page by category) this works when page loads and works when i press "Сортировка по названию" at the popover, but when i click second time this shows no aSorter[0], why?

Comment: you forgot "new" to create a sorter instance ||
var oSorter = **new** sap.ui.model.Sorter("count", !oDescending);

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! please last question. https://jsfiddle.net/kj9ah6yh/ is there any makeup errors here?